# how to create predicate of the jpa specification or criteria query for the below query

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, criteria

I am trying to create JPA specification for with filter data between two dates date1 and date2, I tried to create through subquery but no luck as of now, please help if possible.
I am trying to create the specification for the below SQL query,

```
select
    * from
    subscription sub join (
        select subscription_id,
        max(output_date) as max_output_date
    from
        subscription_package
    where
        package_status = 'COMPLETE'
    group by
        subscription_id) sp on
    sub.id = sp.subscription_id where
    max_output_date between 'date1' and 'date2'
```

Below is the query created in JPA:

```
            Subquery<Date> datequery = query
            .subquery(Date.class);
        Root<SubscriptionPackage> dateRoot = datequery
            .from(SubscriptionPackage.class);

        Subquery<SubscriptionPackage> subquery = query
            .subquery(SubscriptionPackage.class);
        Root<SubscriptionPackage> subqueryRoot = subquery
            .from(SubscriptionPackage.class);

        datequery.select(criteriaBuilder
            .greatest(subqueryRoot.<Date>get("outputDate")));
        datequery.where(criteriaBuilder.equal(subqueryRoot.get("PackageStatus"),
                'COMPLETE'));
        datequery.groupBy(subqueryRoot.get("subscription"));
```

not able to use the result from date query for the comparison like

```
query.where(criteriaBuilder.between(datequery., outFrom, outTo));
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you are using Subquery and you can use simple Spring data jpa with joins get your desire result.
[Please check these examples](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-data/combined-specifications.html)

For date comparison:

```
criteriaBuilder.between(root.get("createdDate"), fromDate, toDate));
```

Comment: Here in between clause i have to pass the the max_output_date  (which will be selected date and can be multiple ) , please look at sql query

Comment: Please check shared examples you need to leared ListJoin then you can easily resolve your problem.